# Positioning AwtWindow with a FileDialog in the center of the screen

Tags: windows, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, awt, desktop-application

I'd like to position a `FileDialog` in the center of the screen in my Jetpack Compose Deskop app. I've got the base snippet from an example [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/9e25001e9e3a6be96668e38c7f0bd222c54d1388/tutorials/Window_API_new/README.md?plain=1#L547).

I tried to extend it by adding the `apply` extension that sets the position on the screen before showing the dialog, but as you can probably already guess, it doesn't work. The `size` property is `0, 0` and setting it do any other `Dimention` (as in the commented out line) doesn't have any effect. Neither its size nor its position changes.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.window.AwtWindow
import java.awt.*

@Composable
fun PickExcelFileDialog(parent: Frame? = null, onCloseRequest: (result: String?) -> Unit) {
    AwtWindow(
        create = {
            object : FileDialog(parent, "Pick excel file to import", LOAD) {
                override fun setVisible(value: Boolean) {
                    super.setVisible(value)
                    if (value) {
                        onCloseRequest(file)
                    }
                }
            }.apply {
                // size = Dimension(200, 300)
                val screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().screenSize
                val dialogSize = size
                location = Point().apply {
                    x = (dialogSize.width - screenSize.width) / 2
                    y = (dialogSize.height - screenSize.height) / 2
                }
            }
        },
        dispose = FileDialog::dispose
    )
}
```

What technique would work in this case?